# JQuery Ajax Post/Get Not Sending Data But Retrieves Data From The Page

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, get

For some reason, JQuery Ajax isnt sending the data. Yes, similar question has been asked here but none of the answers works in my case, tried both `$.get` and `$.post` or even `$.ajax` and specifying `post` or `get`, none works, I get an `undefined variable` error, but however Ajax does retrieve the data sent back from the page ie. it does `load` **ajax-user-summary.php** page

```
 $('#user-menu li:nth-child(1)').click(function(e) {
      $.post('Includes/ajax-user-summary.php', { user_id: 10667546, user: "Darlington Akogo"}, function(status) {
       $('.user-record-interface').load("Includes/ajax-user-summary.php");
      });
   });
```

Comment: Will work as-is. problem is elsewhere. (note that you're making two ajax calls, one posts with data, the other gets without data and then appends result of request without data to page)

Comment: Omgggg...I was quite certain loading the page(using its url) after sending it data is the same as loading the `data` in an Ajax Function, but then I thought about your comment and just decided to use `load(data)`/`html(data)` in requesting returned results and you were right!! 
cant believe something so trivial got me stuck for ages! lol THANKS, BRO!!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#user-menu li:nth-child(1)').click(function(e) {

var data = {user_id: 10667546, user: "Darlington Akogo"};

$.ajax( {
         url:'Includes/ajax-patient-summary.php',
         data:data,success:function(status){
                      $('.patient-record-interface').load("Includes/ajax-user-summary.php");

                      });
});
```